# SImple Data storing In android with Sqlite Show Error

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-database

I want to store simple form data in database with Sqlite. Application gets install and also show activity layout but when we fill and click on submit button then application shows unfortunately apk has stoped.where i am getting wrong in code?

My Main.class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Main extends Activity{
Intent i=null;
EditText tv1,tv2;
SQLiteDatabase db=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    tv2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.altnumber);
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists login(name varchar,altnumber varchar)");}


public void action(View v) {

    String name = tv1.getText().toString();
    String altnumber = tv2.getText().toString();

    db.execSQL("insert into login values('" + name + "','" + altnumber + "')");
    i = new Intent(this, Welcome.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 500);
    db.close();
    finish();


 }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.milind.splach.Main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:text="Data Base" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Tutorials Point"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:textColor="#ff16ff01" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/altnumber"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/altnumber"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="action" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need to debug your app step by step to identify the problem.

Comment: apllication is successfully debuged and there is n error shows in Android Studio but application gives me error when i click on submit.

Comment: @MilindP.Chaudhari NUll
INTEGER
REAL
TEXT
BLOB
types are supported in sqllite for android.varchar is not. text is the option for you moreover is you are learning then follow this articl ehttp://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: @user2299040 would please send me a link again. link is not working properly.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/